# Unable to add conda Python3 environment to existing Python2 Jupyter environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook running on a Python 2.7 Anaconda environment. I would like to add a Python 3 environment to the notebook. Per many various Internet guides, I have tried many variations on the following commands:

```
$ sudo /usr/anaconda2/bin/python -m ipykernel install --prefix=/home/madwand/.conda/envs/PostTrans --name PostTrans
[InstallIPythonKernelSpecApp] WARNING | Installing to /home/madwand/.conda/envs/PostTrans/share/jupyter/kernels, which is not in ['/home/madwand/.local/share/jupyter/kernels', '/usr/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels', '/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels', '/usr/share/jupyter/kernels', u'/home/madwand/.ipython/kernels']. The kernelspec may not be found.
Installed kernelspec PostTrans in /home/madwand/.conda/envs/PostTrans/share/jupyter/kernels/posttrans
```

I can check that the environment is installed correctly as follows:

```
$ sudo /usr/anaconda2/bin/python /usr/anaconda2/bin/jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2      /usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  posttrans    /home/madwand/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/posttrans
```

However, the "PostTrans" environment does not show up in the Jupyter notebook no matter what I do. What is going wrong, and what can I do to get the notebook to recognize the Python 3 environment?

Comment: Have you tried not using ``sudo``? Because you have used ``sudo``, there is a chance you may now have issues as this would update stuff in your home account and leave it owned by ``root``. You may have to go fix ownership of files and directories under ``/home/madwand/.local`` now.

Comment: Yes, my first try was without sudo. When it didn't work, I tried to use sudo to see if it would put the files somewhere else other than my home directory. It didn't work.